# Hyperledger fabric endorsement policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to know the possibility of implementing below scenario w.r.t HLFabric.

(A) Have peer0 and peer1 under Org1 and peer 0 under Org2 and Peer0 under Org3.

(B) Endorsement policy as 1-of (peer1 of Org1, peer0 of Org2, peer0 of Org3).

When we tried above scenario it is working fine with all endorsing nodes up and running. But when I make one of peer1 of Org1 or peer0 of Org2 or peer0 of Org3 down purposefully just to simulate that the Blockchain network works even if one of the endorsing nodes goes down. But what I observed is the putState transaction is failing if all the peers are not in running state.

Please note that I would like to run individual peers in different hyperledger fabric organizations from different geo-graphical regions or managed by different networks. In such a case, I would like to know if any of endorsing peers goes down how to make the blockchain network running without any failure.

Can above scenario be achieved?

Comment: How do you build that policy? Policies are referred to organizations and roles, but not to specific peers....

Comment: If I am not wrong can you please validate if this is your endorsement policy:
`"OR('Org1MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.peer')"`. Also, please make a note that as @kekomal suggests, you cannot refer policies to particular peers inside the organization.

Comment: We are using below code at the time of instantiating chaincode using sendInstantiateProposal method. var req = {targets:'peer0.example.org', 
chaincodeId : 'clog'
chaincodeVersion  : 'v1'
chaincodeType..  : 'node', args: , txId:tx_id, 'endorsement-policy':{identities:[{role:{name:'member',mspId:'Org1MSP'}},{role:{name:'member',mspId:'Org2MSP'}},{role:{name:'member',mspId:'Org3MSP'}}], policy:{'1-of':[{'signed-by':0},{'signed-by':1,{'signed-by':2}}]}}}

Answer (score 0):

Understand it this way. There are organizations which don't trust each other, but want to do business.

Org1, Org2 and Org3. The agreement is that, a business transaction goes through only if all of the three orgs agree for it. This means that all of them will have to participate in endorsement policy, and the way they do it is via peers. Now, this means that one peer should be UP per org for each of the orgs to be part of endorsement.

In a case where each org has multiple peers, the other peer is only for 'backup' is my understanding (am not sure about this). In your case, Org1 has two peers, and remaining two have one peer each. If you are pulling down any of the peers in Org2 and Org3 down, then they cannot participate in the endorsement process, and the original problem statement of "Three orgs don't trust each other and still would like to do business" is lost. That is the reason HLF is failing 'putState'.

Have atleast one peer per Org, and things should work.

If your endorsement policy has "OR('Org1MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.peer')" like others have pointed out, this means that putState will work as long as any one org has a peer UP. This means that the original problem statement of "three orgs don't trust each other but still want to do business" is changing to "three orgs trust each other and can do business if any of them endorses it". You need to understand if this suits your business case.

I haven't tested this myself, but am putting across my understanding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We are using HLF 1.4 version. My intention here is to test when the signing policy is defined as '1-of':[
                    {
                        'signed-by':0
                    },
                    {
                        'signed-by':1
                    },
                    {
                        'signed-by':2
                    }
                ]

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your requirement, the request object for instantiating the chaincode as minor correction. The correct object should look something like this:

```
{
    targets:'peer0.example.org', 
    chaincodeId : 'clog',
    chaincodeVersion : 'v1',
    chaincodeType.. : 'node', 
    args: , 
    txId:tx_id, 
    'endorsement-policy':
        {
        identities:
            [{
                role:
                {
                    name:'member',
                    mspId:'Org1MSP'
                }
             },
             {
                role:
                {
                    name:'member',
                    mspId:'Org2MSP'
                }
             },
             {
                role:
                {
                    name:'member',
                    mspId:'Org3MSP'
                }
             }
            ], 
            policy:{
                '1-of':[
                    {
                        'signed-by':0
                    },
                    {
                        'signed-by':1
                    },
                    {
                        'signed-by':2
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

If you look closely, the error is there in policy section, for the way you have placed `'signed-by':2` inside the other block of `'signed-by':1`.

Also, please note that we cannot have ability to restrict the policies to point to specific peers of the organization. Here, also if you want a stricter policy, you can change the 'role' type to `peer` instead of using `member`.

Apart from that, if your discovery service is not running, please make sure you are sending your transaction proposal to every peer in the network to receive valid number of endorsements.